# Why is this function breaking when it is placed inside of a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, es6-promise

I have a promise that retrieves entries from my Firebase Realtime Database, and using a callback, checks if the specific entries were made on today's date. The callback function (which works when not in the promise) results in the following error when I move it inside of the promise:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkIfEntryFromToday' of null

I have tried binding .this to the function in my constructor, but that does not help.

Here is the code:

***Main function that calls the promise***

```
getUsersHydration(){
    return new Promise (resolve => {
      const ref = this.props.firebase.db.ref(this.state.user)
      ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
        const userObject = (snapshot.val());
        //pull ounces out of object and checks if the entry was made today
        const dailyOunces = []
        for (const key in userObject) {
          let currentVal = userObject[key].ounces
          let dateOfEntry = userObject[key].date
          if (this.checkIfEntryFromToday(dateOfEntry)){
            dailyOunces.push(currentVal)
          }
        }
        //sums the total ounces 
        const sum = dailyOunces.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0)
        resolve(sum)
      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });
    })
  }
```

***function checkIfEntryFromToday that creates the error***

```
checkIfEntryFromToday(milsToEvaluate){
    const dayOfEntry = this.findDayByMils(milsToEvaluate)
    const today = this.findDayByMils(new Date())
    if (dayOfEntry === today) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
```

***function called in checkIfEntryFromToday (maybe irrelevant, but since it's called I'll post it)***

```
findDayByMils(givenDate){
    //takes in the miliseconds and converts to string representing date
    const date = new Date(givenDate)
    const year = date.getFullYear().toString()
    const day = date.getDay().toString()
    const month = date.getMonth().toString()
    const combinedDate = (day + year + month)
    return combinedDate
  }
```

Comment: Before the line `if (this.checkIfEntryFromToday(dateOfEntry)){`, add `console.log(this);`.  What does the log say the `this` variable is?  It's probably not what you are expecting.  I *think* it'll be the `ref` object.

Comment: @Amy console.log(this) on a line right above the if statement returns null

Comment: When you call `checkIfEntryFromToday` then `this` is not really the scope what you are looking for.

Comment: The reason you're seeing this is because of `ref.on("value", function(snapshot) { ...` - if you want to preserve `this`, you _have_ to use arrow functions. That `function(snapshot)` is going to get its `this` from its execution context (which will be whatever is the global context) rather than getting `this` from its _declaration_ context. You're already doing this earlier, so the simple observation would be "just do that again", but the more pertinent question is "why did you even use a `function` here?"

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem: `ref.on("value", function(snapshot){`

You are using an anonymous function. Anonymous functions change `this` to be in the scope of the function (and you can't access the outside scope using `this`).

To get around the issue, change that line to: `ref.on("value", snapshot => {`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with whether the function you pass is anonymous or not.  In fact the fat arrow function (that works properly) is also anonymous.  If you use a separately declared, named function (which is not anonymous), you'd have the same problem.  The issue is any function other than a fat arrow function will change the value of `this`.  Fat arrow functions were invented for this specific purpose.  So, you have the right solution, but your reference to anonymous being the cause is just wrong.